# How to upgrade the ALSA driver?

Tags: 10.04, alsa

I am using Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS. How can I upgrade the ALSA driver from 1.0.20 to 1.0.23?

Comment: why do you need 1.0.23 (the version from maverick)?  If you uplift your 10.04.1 to 10.04.3 you will have v1.0.22 - any reasons why your computer is 12-18 months without security patches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should follow the Ubuntu official guide about sound issues, specifically in the step 1 for your Ubuntu version:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure#Step 1

It helps you upgrading alsa packages in the safest way at the versions available at these PPA:

https://launchpad.net/~team-iquik/+archive/alsa/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=lucid

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=lucid